# importing entry status via CSV - does uppercase or lowercase status matter

Tags: status, datagrab, import, query-module

I typically add/edit/delete my entries via CSV (datagrab) and have been doing so for a while now. Recently I'm seeing some confusing things in the way that some of my entries were being ordered and displayed and I noticed that during one of my imports, I had updated statuses to 'Open' while some of the other entries are 'open'.  Both statuses seem to display, but which is actually correct?

The site is on EE 3.4.5 and I'm pulling entries via a SELECT DISTINCT query

```
WHERE exp_channel_data.channel_id='2' AND status='open'
```

The query pulls the same number of results regardless of the case of the status.

Which one is actually correct per EE standards? open/Open closed/Closed
For that matter what about all caps?

Note that on EE2 if you check the default status it shows Open/Closed as status names, but if you open the status it shows open/closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While firing a query in DB, No matter you pass "Open" or "open". Both are same.

Your first question's answer is: **As per EE Standards, It should be "open".**

EE save "open/closed" in database, it shows in list page after making "first letter" capitalized.